# How to create a list in Python that will yield the following result []

Tags: python

This a question on coursera practices excess.

Create a new list using the 9th through 12th elements (four items in all) of new_lst and assign it to the variable sub_lst.

link to the question: https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/fopp/Sequences/TheSliceOperator.html
The last question on the list.

**How is my code**

```
new_lst = ["computer", "luxurious", "basket", "crime", 0, 2.49, "institution", "slice", "sun", 
["water", "air", "fire", "earth"], "games", 2.7, "code", "java", ["birthday", "celebration", 1817, 
"party", "cake", 5], "rain", "thunderstorm", "top down"]
new_lst = new_lst[9:12]
sub_lst = new_lst
print(sub_lst)
```

My output:

```
[['water', 'air', 'fire', 'earth'], 'games', 2.7]
```

But here is the expected output:

```
['sun', ['water', 'air', 'fire', 'earth'], 'games', 2.7]
```

Please why am I not getting the expected output?

Comment: Please add a link to original question here.

Comment: Possibly because you destroyed `new_lst` in the process?  You should have assigned the slice directly to `sub_lst` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are  assigning  more than the question asked and here is the solution

```
new_lst = ["computer", "luxurious", "basket", "crime", 0, 2.49, "institution", "slice", "sun", ["water", "air", "fire", "earth"], "games", 2.7, "code", "java", ["birthday", "celebration", 1817, "party", "cake", 5], "rain", "thunderstorm", "top down"]
sub_lst = new_lst[8:12]
```

just   do "sub_lst = new_lst[8:12]" assign just sliced list in sub_lst.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start indexing at 8 as The 9th element is at index 8.

```
new_lst = ["computer", "luxurious", "basket", "crime", 0, 2.49, "institution", "slice", "sun", ["water", "air", "fire", "earth"], "games", 2.7, "code", "java", ["birthday", "celebration", 1817, "party", "cake", 5], "rain", "thunderstorm", "top down"]

sub_lst=new_lst[8:8+4]
```

Resulting output will be -

```
['sun', ['water', 'air', 'fire', 'earth'], 'games', 2.7]
```

Answer (score 0):

your 9th element is ['water', 'air', 'fire', 'earth'] (it is included) and 12th element is "code" (it is excluded in python)
so result is [['water', 'air', 'fire', 'earth'], 'games', 2.7]

Comment: Yes The result is [['water', 'air', 'fire', 'earth'], 'games', 2.7] But from the online textbook the The Expected Result **[ ]**  https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/fopp/Sequences/TheSliceOperator.html

Comment: At that book expected answer is not empty array your answer is ```new_lst = ["computer", "luxurious", "basket", "crime", 0, 2.49, "institution", "slice", "sun", ["water", "air", "fire", "earth"], "games", 2.7, "code", "java", ["birthday", "celebration", 1817, "party", "cake", 5], "rain", "thunderstorm", "top down"]

sub_lst=new_lst[8:12]```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a simple output of the 9th through 12th items of the list

```
item_count = 0
for item in new_lst:
    item_count += 1
    if 9<=item_count<=12:
        print(str(item_count)+" "+str(item))
```

you get the output

```
9 sun
10 ['water', 'air', 'fire', 'earth']
11 games
12 2.7
```

which is not an empty list.

To get the sub-list of the 9th through 12th items use a slice that starts at 8 based on a zero-based index and ends at 12 because the last item is not included in the output slice.

```
sub_lst = new_lst[8:12]
```

which prints as

```
print(sub_lst)
['sun', ['water', 'air', 'fire', 'earth'], 'games', 2.7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I executed in the link you have provided:

```
new_lst = ["computer", "luxurious", "basket", "crime", 0, 2.49, "institution", "slice", "sun", ["water", "air", "fire", "earth"], "games", 2.7, "code", "java", ["birthday", "celebration", 1817, "party", "cake", 5], "rain", "thunderstorm", "top down"]
sub_lst = new_lst[8:12]
print(sub_lst)
```

This line in the code you have written, you have updated the value of new_lst to only 4 elements.

```
new_lst = new_lst[9:12]
```

So, it is showing the expected value as [].